# Getting an error when Accessing the java objects from another JS file. this.firstinput=element(by.model("first"));element is not defined

Tags: javascript, protractor

````
//Jsobjectdemo.js:

function  car() {
    
    
    this.firstinput=element(by.model("first"));
    this.secondinput=element(by.model("second"));
    this.goButton=element(by.id("gobutton"));
    this.result=element(by.css("h2[class='ng-binding']"));
    this.color="red"; this.engine="turbo"; this.brand="BMW";
    this.search="by.css('input')";
    
    this.getURL=function() {
    
    browser.get('http://juliemr.github.io/protractor-demo/'); };
    
    };  
    module.exports= new car();

    
//JsAccess.js:

```var obj=  require("./Jsobjectdemo.js");      
   obj.getModel();
   console.log(obj.search);
````

Comment: JAVA objects from JAVASCRIPT files?

Comment: need to create a object of function  car()  in (Jsobjectdemo.js:)and access it from JsAccess.js file

Answer (score 0):

```
//Jsobjectdemo

const car = {
firstinput :element(by.model("first")),
secondinput : element(by.model("second")),
goButton : element(by.id("gobutton")),
result : element(by.css("h2[class='ng-binding']")),
color : "red", engine : "turbo", brand : "BMW",
search : "by.css('input')",
getURL : function () {
    browser.get('http://juliemr.github.io/protractor-demo/')
}
}
exports.car = car;

//JsAccess.js:
const {car} = require(`./Jsobjectdemo`)

console.log(car.search)
```

Note : element and by must be imported from protractor in the pages file

```
const {by, element, browser} = require('protractor');
```

Comment: I add code line to Jsobjectdemo file const {by, element, browser} = require('protractor'); but IDE says "  Error: Cannot find module 'protractor'" appreciate your reply.Can you provide more details because I am a beginner to JS and Protractor.
I am runing this in windows env so is there a issue in path of the require function

Comment: You need to install protractor. Run npm i protractor --save.

Comment: I install protractor in my project folder (Run npm i protractor --save).But it did not work for me